# Official BigCommerce-api-ruby gem not using OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, bigcommerce

So I know that BigCommerce is transitioning completely over to OAuth soon, but their "official" ruby gem still uses the old API key authentication (from connection.rb):

```
"#{@configuration[:store_url]}/api/v2#{path}.json"
```

I'm considering transitioning over to the unofficial community-based bigcommerce_api gem instead, but then I'll have to change the api calls in most cases inside of my code.

Thoughts?  Does anyone know if BigCommerce is going to update their gem before the transition is complete?

Comment: I don't think they have said. My sense in watching the transition has been that it seems they moving away from these "official" code sets - Ruby, PHP, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they've mentioned an exact time when they transition completely to OAuth yet.

However, I've made [this gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bigcommerce-oauth-api) which supports all the current BigCommerce APIs using OAuth.

One of the advantages of my gem is that it uses the same structure as the official gem which makes it easy to switch to using OAuth without having to rewrite your existing code.